# Data Structure to Represent Family Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

I want to have a data structure to represent a family relationship, including mother, father, sister, spouse, etc. One way I am thinking is to have a class of Person and make different fields to represent family members.

```
Pulic Class Person{
    String name;
    Person Father;
    Person Mother;
    List<Person> sister;

}
```

However, when I trying to draw the family graph, I find it is hard to track and traverse the relationship. I am wondering if there is a better data structure or a better way to represent the family relationship.

Comment: Why does a `Person` has a list `sister`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think Kevin meant sibling. and not sister

Comment: Hah.  Good luck with my family! Did you have a plan for half-siblings, exes, steps, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about this as a graph problem.  Graphs have nodes and edges.  A person could be a node, a relationship an edge.  It might look like this:

```
(defstruct person
  name
  birth-date
  birth-place
  ssn)

(defstruct relationship
  from
  to
  type
  start
  end)
```